# Problems with PHP code or a bug

Tags: php

I am having weird issues with my code. I have almost identical code to the one below (I have not provided the actual code b`cuz it is a little big library with a lot of dynamic generation(selecting classes based on path routing etc. i.e. framework)).

The code explained:

**ClassA** represents the current route object. Contains controller, route string etc.

**ScriptAClassAction** is the dispatcher, checking if the route has everything that is necessary for the execution and running everything, does the controller exists `$!empty(reflection)` and does the action exist in the controller `$reflection->hasMethod('hello')`.

In my world the **parent if** should be triggered if both conditions are meant (and the are not) or the else should get triggered, which is checking to see which of the checks have failed. On execution time I see that the first check passes (which I think it is a bug in PHP) and after it the **else** gets triggered, and then the second **if**.

I am thinking that this may be a bug in PHP, but I doubt it a lot. Does anyone see something that I miss @ 1:50AM ?

PHP 5.3.27 with enabled xDebug(No other extensions) & Apache 2.2.25 (I believe Apache is irrelevant here but..), Windows 7 x86 Home Premium

**ClassA.php**

```
class A
{
    public function init()
    {
        print 'Init called';
    }

    public function preDispatch()
    {
        print 'Predispatch called';
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        print 'Hello world';
    }

    public function postDispatch()
    {
        print "Post dispatch";
    }
}
```

**ScriptAClassAction.php**

```
require 'ClassA.php';

$class = new A();
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($class);
if (!empty($reflection) && $reflection->hasMethod('indexAction')) {
    if ($reflection->hasMethod('init')) $class->init($request, $response); //Prints 'Init called'
    if ($reflection->hasMethod('preDispatch')) $class->preDispatch(); // 'Predispatch called' 
    $class->indexAction();
    if ($reflection->hasMethod('postDispatch')) $class->postDispatch(); // 'post dispatch called'..
} else {
    if (!$reflection) // I know this might not be the best check but..
        print "Not a valid class supplied";

    if (false == $reflection->hasMethod('indexAction')) // True trigger
        print "Supplied class does not have any manners and does not greet you :D";
        // This is the expected output and it should be the only output
}
```

** Output **

> Init called Predispatch called Postdospatch called Supplied class does
>   not have any manners and does not greet you :D

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you're trying to achieve. Also, when you construct a new object (`$var = new Class();`), you will **always** end up with an instance inside the variable, except when some critical comes up...in which case the rest of the code is not executed. In other words, your `if(!empty($reflection)` and `if(!$reflection)` checks are completely pointless.

Comment: what's going inside your `hasMethod()`? It may be the source of your false positive.

Comment: I've read the question 5 times. I have no idea what you're actually seeing, that you think is a bug.

Comment: I get the `Supplied class does not have any manners and does not greet you :D` strong echoed, which as far as I can tell is the expected behavior. Please make your question more explicit.

Comment: Sorry guys forgot to provide the output :D Edit: added the actual code in there and this is exactly what is going on.

Comment: *"This is the expected output and it should be the only output"* Well, you're going to have to change the constructor in class A if you want that to be the *only* output. Class A is going to print "Init" every time it's instantiated. Apart from that, and apart from class A not having preDispatch and postDispatch, I have to concur with @Mchl. The code outputs exactly what I'd expect it to.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' Agreed.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' Class a was a test class, but I decided to add the actual code of the dispatch. Should have added the actual code of the Class A as well.

Comment: @victorantunes: It's not the OP's hasMethod(). That's part of the [php Reflection class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.hasmethod.php).

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov: So after your last code revision, you're saying that php executes the statements in *both* the outermost `if` *and* the outermost `else`. Is that right? (I don't see that here with php 5.3.10.)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' confirm :D and it is not only in that case, it is happening in one more kinda similar but not connected if0else statement in the code. On my primary Dev machine (5.3.16) there are no issues as well

Comment: I would advise cleaning up the code, starting with removing the unnecessary checks which I have already pointed out (and which no one seems to notice).

Comment: After changes the output I get is: `Init calledPredispatch calledHello worldPost dispatch`. And again as far as I can tell this is the expected output since `A` has method `indexAction`. If you're getting the `Supplied class does not have any manners and does not greet you :D` string as well, I would suggest checking if you don't run the same code one more time for another object.

Comment: I get the "Init called ..." output also, which is what I expected.  **However**, instead of trying to "fix" this code, I would suggest using an [Interface](http://php.net/interface/) - you're trying to ensure that a particular class includes particular methods; that's exactly what an interface is for. Something like [this](http://gist.github.com/customanything/6331789), maybe.

Comment: Indeed, checking if method exists before calling it i.e. duck typing is a domain of dynamic languages like Ruby or Python. PHP's object model is more Java-like and the use of interfaces and type hints is much more natural in it, than using Reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding brackets to your `if` statements will solve the issue. Also, you don't have to test the `$reflection` variable is empty or not. It will always be an instance.

Like @traq mentioned, it's better to create interfaces to identify classes with certain behaviors.

```
interface DispatchAware {
    public function preDispatch();
    public function postDispatch();
}

class A implements DispatchAware { ... }
```

Now you don't have to check for every method that might exist. You'll know it exists when an class implements an interface.

You dispatch code could now look something like:

```
$action = 'indexAction';

$a = new A();

if ($a instanceof DispatchAware) {
    $a->preDispatch();
}

try {
    $r = new ReflectionClass($a);
    $method = $r->getMethod($action);
    $method->invoke($a, $request, $response);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    methodNotFoundError();
}

if ($a instanceof DispatchAware) {
    $a->postDispatch();
}
```

I also removed the `init()` method. The reason for this is that controller type objects generally don't need to keep state. That is why `$request` and `$response` are passed as arguments to the action method.

Comment: The interface is not an option atm, b`cuz the concept if generally taken from ZF1.X. The pre-,post-dispatches are not required, but optional. Anyways thanks for posting the example I believe it will help me clear the coding a bit more.

Comment: Implementing an interface is optional as well. If the class does only wishes to implement preDispatch it could provide empty methods for the others. Or you could make it a abstract class.